# What caused change in percentile?

Tags: time-series, quantiles

We report 95th percentile and 50th percentile of the time series data for every week. The data is time-series data in the following format
date. sensor_id. sensor_location. hardware_version. sensor_value
2021-01-01. S1. L1. V1. 10.
2021-01-01. S2. L2. V2. 20.
2021-01-01. S3. L1. V1. 12.
2021-02-01. S1. L1. V3. 30.
2021-02-01. S2. L2. V3. 40.
2021-02-01. S3. L1. V2. 32.

The problem we are facing is to understand what caused the change in percentile week over week. For example some weeks the p95 is very high and we would like to know what sensor or which location or which version caused the big jump in p95. Could you please help what's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do the percentiles appear in your table?  Are you trying to say these percentiles summarize the data by sensor by week?  Are you asking how to compute them and do the data processing to identify sensors and versions where the 95th percentiles are high?

Comment: I have computed the percentile for every week and we report them. When the report shows the p95 moved from 10 to 15 often time question come what has been changed in the data that can caused the p95 to go from 10 to 15. I am looking at way to explain this change.